# What is the best way to make sure Array in PHP are closed correctly

Tags: drush

I wonder how to determine when to close an array. I edited a aliases.drush.php and added a database array but now, while I have multiple array I got a syntax error. Is there a easy rule to remember how to close an array without getting syntax errors when a file has about 300 lines?

Comment: Why you need to put the database config in `*.aliases.drush.php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is no longer necessary to put `databases` into your Drush alias file. In older versions of Drush, a `databases` record in an alias file could be used to allow Drush to do an sql-sync to or from a remote system that did not have Drush installed.  This feature is no longer supported, and the `databases` record is no longer necessary.

To answer your specific question, though, any php nested array must have balanced parenthesis.  Make sure that you have one `(` for every `)`. Folks usually keep track of their parenthesis via indentation -- add a level of indentation for each `(`, and remove it for each `)`.

Comment: Der Mr. Anderson. Just a little question about "newer versions" of drush.: Do you mean there are no database entries required for drush 8.x or is this even ported to the 7,x branch?

Comment: I believe that the `databases` feature in sql-sync still existed in Drush 5, but was removed in Drush 6. In any event, it is not present in any supported version of Drush (currently that is Drush 7, 8 and 9).

Answer (score 1):

> how to close an array without getting syntax errors when a file has about 300 lines

Choose a suitable IDE / code editor is very important for coding. Most of the IDE / code editor have aids to help code completion or syntax error detection.

For example, in [SublimeText](https://www.sublimetext.com/), you can install below packages for help:

- [BracketHighlighter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BracketHighlighter)
- [PHP CodeSniffer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Phpcs)